# Lag of values from 1 month ago

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lag

My initial dataset has only 2 columns, date and value.

What I'm trying to do is, for each date, get the value from the previous month (columns m-1 and m-12). The problems I'm having is when the day doesn't exist in previous month, like 29 of February, that I want to leave it empty, and most methods tend to get the nearby dates.

So, the final table would be something like this:

| date | value | m-1 | m-12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-05 | 400 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-05 | 100 | NaN | 400 |
| 2022-01-28 | 300 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-02-05 | 300 | 100 | NaN |
| 2022-02-28 | 500 | 300 | NaN |
| 2022-03-29 | 300 | NaN | NaN |

I was thinking I could use something like `d.apply(lambda x: x['date'] - relativedelta(months = 1), axis=1)` but with this, I only get the date, not the value. And it rounds the dates, for example for 2022-03-29 it returns 2022-02-28 which is not correct, it should be 02-29, and since it doesn't exist it should be NaN.

Comment: Should the 30th of march also return Nan ?

Comment: That would be the idea because at the end the dataset have all days from 2019 to 2022, but the lags of some days doesn't exist, like the lag of m-1 for december 31 (because november doesn't have 31 days). So at the end for those days I prefer it NULL before having a fake number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possiblity :

```py
# 1. necessary imports
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import numpy as np

# 2. build example
df_example = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date", "value"])
df_example.date = ["2021-01-05", "2022-01-05", "2022-01-28", "2022-02-05", "2022-02-28", "2022-03-29"]
df_example.date = pd.to_datetime(df_example.date)
df_example.value = [400, 100, 300, 300, 500, 300]

# 3. look for the value corresponding to a given date
def build_column(row, month_shift, year_shift):
    previous_month_date = f"{row.date.year-year_shift}-{row.date.month-month_shift}-{row.date.day}"
    previous_value_row = df_example[df_example.date == previous_month_date]
    if len(previous_value_row) == 0:
        return np.nan

    return previous_value_row.value.iloc[0]

# 4. add column m1 corresponding to the 1-month shift
df_example["m1"] = df_example.apply(lambda x: build_column(x, 1, 0), axis=1)
df_example["m12"] = df_example.apply(lambda x: build_column(x, 0, 1), axis=1)
```

Which outputs

|  | date | value | m1 | m12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 400 | nan | nan |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 00:00:00 | 100 | nan | 400 |
| 2 | 2022-01-28 00:00:00 | 300 | nan | nan |
| 3 | 2022-02-05 00:00:00 | 300 | 100 | nan |
| 4 | 2022-02-28 00:00:00 | 500 | 300 | nan |
| 5 | 2022-03-29 00:00:00 | 300 | nan | nan |

Comment: I tried it with the big dataset, and it also works perfectly, don't know how I didn't think of that. Probably because I always avoid apply() because I think it hurts performance, but it works great, thanks :D.

Comment: You are welcome :) . I guess that if you modify your input dataset so that you have a row for every day even if it doesn't exist, you may be able to make it more efficient by using a rolling window, or just shifting the indexes by a fixed number of days (that way there is no need to scan the whole dataset to look for the previous month value).